# Brute Force password generator for md5?

Tags: python, hash

So I'm working on a program that will brute force a small password for a project.
for example: 
password hashed is: 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99

I've already figured out how to run a variable through the md5 hashing function, but i'm stuck on how i can try a through z, AND THEN try a-z + a-z (aa, ab, ac...............ba,bb,bc,bd,be.....zz)

Any help would be nice.

all i have so far:

```
import hashlib
hash = "5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99"
charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

complete = 0
while complete == 0:
```

Comment: Read about `itertools.product`

Comment: The fastest way is likely to google it: https://md5hashing.net/hash/md5/5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99/